# Адаптивный Сайдбар, как подстроить по размерам контент?

Tags: html, css, responsive, sidebar

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar--active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
  transition: .3s;
}

.sidebar--active {
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="sidebar sidebar--active"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nesciunt debitis sunt dolores eaque sapiente hic a excepturi! Voluptates cupiditate expedita facere illo? Delectus a deleniti aperiam. Facere, debitis quidem.
  Dolorum velit qui cum maiores autem ducimus. Delectus suscipit natus, blanditiis maxime, vero corporis ea repellat eius facere officiis, laudantium a aperiam rerum rem neque. Tempore ipsum eius est sequi!
  Autem, eaque officia quisquam, doloribus fugit sed reprehenderit cupiditate distinctio quidem sint quo iure minima soluta officiis facere enim vitae minus voluptas. Reiciendis rem consectetur laboriosam mollitia velit nihil cumque.
  Reiciendis repellendus recusandae voluptatum asperiores similique delectus dicta rerum. Repellat maxime molestiae omnis itaque neque provident adipisci quis, pariatur sunt non? Animi provident ut repellendus? Beatae minus explicabo odio similique.
  Corporis, facilis. Architecto hic cupiditate impedit sit dolorem reiciendis accusamus. Repellat fugit tempore mollitia voluptatibus neque maxime harum quis laboriosam officia, consequuntur veniam, voluptatem adipisci. Suscipit nostrum eius velit rerum?
  Eaque iusto repudiandae nulla quia voluptatibus ratione architecto sed. Porro ipsum odit aperiam quos in veritatis necessitatibus ad, qui minima neque minus eligendi? Nihil cumque dolorem ut, at natus ea!
  Sint autem harum consectetur, ipsum deleniti amet voluptatibus iure voluptatum corporis ratione sit blanditiis eum, recusandae dolore mollitia dolorem praesentium sequi hic? Cupiditate, quis? Ab possimus ad numquam molestiae iusto!
  Eum dicta laborum quidem consequatur aspernatur voluptatem! Odio perspiciatis impedit voluptates quae mollitia qui magnam nihil ea asperiores, pariatur adipisci quidem eius quibusdam, sed, expedita commodi explicabo est repellat numquam!
  Quis qui officiis, laboriosam laudantium, quaerat animi praesentium est perferendis sapiente blanditiis eveniet ducimus autem cumque. Sed facilis repellendus error dolorem eum hic magni necessitatibus! Nisi facere ratione quasi aspernatur.
  Quidem sequi quis vel facere quo, modi est explicabo repudiandae veritatis suscipit, rerum quaerat ipsa sit repellat eveniet, ab cumque temporibus optio fuga? Accusantium possimus nam fugit id, culpa tenetur?
  Veritatis qui recusandae non quos aliquam explicabo corrupti tempora nostrum cumque enim exercitationem fuga quia tempore, numquam, quo, excepturi consequuntur at maxime alias sed illum libero beatae! Id, eaque dolores.
  Eaque aut illum ab architecto? Commodi asperiores vel tempora odit tenetur sit quae quaerat sapiente cupiditate exercitationem eum amet, deleniti impedit dicta, quo, eligendi quasi voluptatem similique velit id consectetur?
  Impedit minima, consequatur error, cupiditate vel veritatis tempore labore voluptas laboriosam obcaecati ad accusantium? Magnam facere, odio quibusdam minus ut obcaecati molestiae maiores magni sapiente sed, quas ex doloribus porro!
  Ab dignissimos animi, ullam voluptatum praesentium repellat at fugiat ratione debitis laboriosam reiciendis est repellendus itaque voluptatem veniam saepe. Quo rem aspernatur, aliquam reiciendis modi quaerat consectetur quas saepe natus!
  Reprehenderit corrupti, enim dicta eos voluptate consequatur eaque iure excepturi laboriosam optio? Cumque commodi neque minima hic earum. Quas animi nisi libero earum iusto pariatur doloribus sequi neque, atque ratione.
  Pariatur eius et reprehenderit? Facere molestias doloribus vero, tempora velit dolorum earum quo nemo consequatur. Saepe ipsam itaque illo vero ad deserunt, nesciunt mollitia sint explicabo laboriosam blanditiis. Autem, non.
  Aut, quam tenetur illum officiis impedit ipsam aliquam qui accusamus deserunt fuga saepe tempora odit fugit, soluta natus doloribus doloremque cupiditate sapiente blanditiis aspernatur similique quod? Est cumque cupiditate accusantium.
  Ad eos consequatur minus labore illum nobis! Voluptatibus laborum quasi molestias, distinctio itaque quis obcaecati corporis ratione voluptates doloribus nostrum voluptas porro. Corrupti officia iure deleniti dignissimos temporibus unde velit.
  Optio, ullam! Quos, aliquam! Voluptatem eaque est odit vitae aspernatur! Molestias fuga ex rem et architecto ut distinctio enim at accusamus earum harum cupiditate deserunt consequuntur voluptate, placeat, aspernatur corrupti.
  Illum fugit obcaecati, laudantium expedita iure sed omnis! Et facilis hic quo illo explicabo, quia itaque ab minima nihil incidunt impedit atque, earum maiores sit nesciunt rerum sapiente nostrum doloremque?
  Placeat illo delectus dicta quo adipisci consequatur vel excepturi mollitia earum laborum! Vero voluptas eum veniam necessitatibus accusamus. Maiores dicta non animi quis expedita deleniti libero consectetur voluptate repellat harum.
  Sunt quisquam necessitatibus velit perferendis. Vero saepe, eos perspiciatis placeat maiores quod veritatis officiis ratione, commodi incidunt inventore! Nisi consectetur deleniti debitis ullam sunt veritatis numquam doloribus quasi harum maiores?
  Harum, doloribus nemo nihil aperiam voluptates ex, autem deserunt dolorum cum sapiente asperiores? Quisquam nostrum, suscipit unde ducimus magnam accusantium ad aut molestiae maxime, non facilis dicta officia quae sequi.
  Velit nihil officia sequi tempore mollitia voluptatem, facilis fugit fugiat voluptate in a ad consequatur earum ut est voluptatibus eum exercitationem quae! Sequi deleniti culpa iusto numquam nemo, est dolorem.
  Reprehenderit exercitationem cupiditate, odio at praesentium officiis laudantium, dolores consequatur illum, pariatur vel. Sequi voluptate temporibus totam blanditiis voluptatibus exercitationem alias aut iure, dolores eius amet unde. Ducimus, perspiciatis. Accusamus.
  Unde iste praesentium nobis obcaecati consequatur! Optio est fugit veritatis, accusantium saepe deserunt officiis ad, distinctio minima, dolorum atque debitis consequuntur doloribus quod suscipit natus eius quos. Delectus, laboriosam reiciendis!
  Quam maxime saepe officia asperiores expedita voluptatibus explicabo voluptates quo, recusandae magni architecto at nulla, perspiciatis ut qui, doloribus fuga ducimus odit ipsam necessitatibus nisi molestias autem quas quis. Maiores?
  Quisquam itaque ipsum dolore quos hic voluptates incidunt, totam atque deserunt animi non, odit libero reiciendis temporibus voluptatibus sunt laborum quasi velit? Vero et obcaecati cum molestiae? Vitae, ab dolor?
  Quaerat eligendi ipsam doloremque magnam aliquam vel odio blanditiis a. Ex pariatur, nobis in cumque facere possimus quod aspernatur ducimus officia perspiciatis voluptas dolorum error omnis aliquid, voluptatibus nam? Aperiam.
  Commodi repudiandae at consequuntur rerum quia in animi! Labore voluptatibus vitae, libero laudantium ab recusandae consequatur velit sit! Doloremque, neque similique repellat quae eligendi ullam optio blanditiis vero? Tenetur, quam!
</div>
```

Подскажите как сделать так чтобы в пк версий меню не перекрывало контент, сайдбар и контент был виден. В моб. версий наоборот может перекрывать. Может есть готовые решения?

Answer (score 1):

Примерно вот так. Для того, чтобы пряталось на мобильном - проверяйте ширину экрана перед вставкой `content--sidebar--active`

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const sidebar = document.querySelector('.sidebar');
const content = document.querySelector('.content');
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('sidebar--active');
  content.classList.toggle('content--sidebar--active');
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 56px;
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  top: 0;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #111;
  transition: .3s;
}

.sidebar--active {
  left: 0;
}

.content {
  transition: .3s;
}

.content--sidebar--active {
  padding-left: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
<div class="sidebar"></div>
<div class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Iure nesciunt debitis sunt dolores eaque sapiente hic a excepturi! Voluptates cupiditate expedita facere illo? Delectus a deleniti aperiam. Facere, debitis quidem.
  Dolorum velit qui cum maiores autem ducimus. Delectus suscipit natus, blanditiis maxime, vero corporis ea repellat eius facere officiis, laudantium a aperiam rerum rem neque. Tempore ipsum eius est sequi!
  Autem, eaque officia quisquam, doloribus fugit sed reprehenderit cupiditate distinctio quidem sint quo iure minima soluta officiis facere enim vitae minus voluptas. Reiciendis rem consectetur laboriosam mollitia velit nihil cumque.
  Reiciendis repellendus recusandae voluptatum asperiores similique delectus dicta rerum. Repellat maxime molestiae omnis itaque neque provident adipisci quis, pariatur sunt non? Animi provident ut repellendus? Beatae minus explicabo odio similique.
  Corporis, facilis. Architecto hic cupiditate impedit sit dolorem reiciendis accusamus. Repellat fugit tempore mollitia voluptatibus neque maxime harum quis laboriosam officia, consequuntur veniam, voluptatem adipisci. Suscipit nostrum eius velit rerum?
  Eaque iusto repudiandae nulla quia voluptatibus ratione architecto sed. Porro ipsum odit aperiam quos in veritatis necessitatibus ad, qui minima neque minus eligendi? Nihil cumque dolorem ut, at natus ea!
  Sint autem harum consectetur, ipsum deleniti amet voluptatibus iure voluptatum corporis ratione sit blanditiis eum, recusandae dolore mollitia dolorem praesentium sequi hic? Cupiditate, quis? Ab possimus ad numquam molestiae iusto!
  Eum dicta laborum quidem consequatur aspernatur voluptatem! Odio perspiciatis impedit voluptates quae mollitia qui magnam nihil ea asperiores, pariatur adipisci quidem eius quibusdam, sed, expedita commodi explicabo est repellat numquam!
  Quis qui officiis, laboriosam laudantium, quaerat animi praesentium est perferendis sapiente blanditiis eveniet ducimus autem cumque. Sed facilis repellendus error dolorem eum hic magni necessitatibus! Nisi facere ratione quasi aspernatur.
  Quidem sequi quis vel facere quo, modi est explicabo repudiandae veritatis suscipit, rerum quaerat ipsa sit repellat eveniet, ab cumque temporibus optio fuga? Accusantium possimus nam fugit id, culpa tenetur?
  Veritatis qui recusandae non quos aliquam explicabo corrupti tempora nostrum cumque enim exercitationem fuga quia tempore, numquam, quo, excepturi consequuntur at maxime alias sed illum libero beatae! Id, eaque dolores.
  Eaque aut illum ab architecto? Commodi asperiores vel tempora odit tenetur sit quae quaerat sapiente cupiditate exercitationem eum amet, deleniti impedit dicta, quo, eligendi quasi voluptatem similique velit id consectetur?
  Impedit minima, consequatur error, cupiditate vel veritatis tempore labore voluptas laboriosam obcaecati ad accusantium? Magnam facere, odio quibusdam minus ut obcaecati molestiae maiores magni sapiente sed, quas ex doloribus porro!
  Ab dignissimos animi, ullam voluptatum praesentium repellat at fugiat ratione debitis laboriosam reiciendis est repellendus itaque voluptatem veniam saepe. Quo rem aspernatur, aliquam reiciendis modi quaerat consectetur quas saepe natus!
  Reprehenderit corrupti, enim dicta eos voluptate consequatur eaque iure excepturi laboriosam optio? Cumque commodi neque minima hic earum. Quas animi nisi libero earum iusto pariatur doloribus sequi neque, atque ratione.
  Pariatur eius et reprehenderit? Facere molestias doloribus vero, tempora velit dolorum earum quo nemo consequatur. Saepe ipsam itaque illo vero ad deserunt, nesciunt mollitia sint explicabo laboriosam blanditiis. Autem, non.
  Aut, quam tenetur illum officiis impedit ipsam aliquam qui accusamus deserunt fuga saepe tempora odit fugit, soluta natus doloribus doloremque cupiditate sapiente blanditiis aspernatur similique quod? Est cumque cupiditate accusantium.
  Ad eos consequatur minus labore illum nobis! Voluptatibus laborum quasi molestias, distinctio itaque quis obcaecati corporis ratione voluptates doloribus nostrum voluptas porro. Corrupti officia iure deleniti dignissimos temporibus unde velit.
  Optio, ullam! Quos, aliquam! Voluptatem eaque est odit vitae aspernatur! Molestias fuga ex rem et architecto ut distinctio enim at accusamus earum harum cupiditate deserunt consequuntur voluptate, placeat, aspernatur corrupti.
  Illum fugit obcaecati, laudantium expedita iure sed omnis! Et facilis hic quo illo explicabo, quia itaque ab minima nihil incidunt impedit atque, earum maiores sit nesciunt rerum sapiente nostrum doloremque?
  Placeat illo delectus dicta quo adipisci consequatur vel excepturi mollitia earum laborum! Vero voluptas eum veniam necessitatibus accusamus. Maiores dicta non animi quis expedita deleniti libero consectetur voluptate repellat harum.
  Sunt quisquam necessitatibus velit perferendis. Vero saepe, eos perspiciatis placeat maiores quod veritatis officiis ratione, commodi incidunt inventore! Nisi consectetur deleniti debitis ullam sunt veritatis numquam doloribus quasi harum maiores?
  Harum, doloribus nemo nihil aperiam voluptates ex, autem deserunt dolorum cum sapiente asperiores? Quisquam nostrum, suscipit unde ducimus magnam accusantium ad aut molestiae maxime, non facilis dicta officia quae sequi.
  Velit nihil officia sequi tempore mollitia voluptatem, facilis fugit fugiat voluptate in a ad consequatur earum ut est voluptatibus eum exercitationem quae! Sequi deleniti culpa iusto numquam nemo, est dolorem.
  Reprehenderit exercitationem cupiditate, odio at praesentium officiis laudantium, dolores consequatur illum, pariatur vel. Sequi voluptate temporibus totam blanditiis voluptatibus exercitationem alias aut iure, dolores eius amet unde. Ducimus, perspiciatis. Accusamus.
  Unde iste praesentium nobis obcaecati consequatur! Optio est fugit veritatis, accusantium saepe deserunt officiis ad, distinctio minima, dolorum atque debitis consequuntur doloribus quod suscipit natus eius quos. Delectus, laboriosam reiciendis!
  Quam maxime saepe officia asperiores expedita voluptatibus explicabo voluptates quo, recusandae magni architecto at nulla, perspiciatis ut qui, doloribus fuga ducimus odit ipsam necessitatibus nisi molestias autem quas quis. Maiores?
  Quisquam itaque ipsum dolore quos hic voluptates incidunt, totam atque deserunt animi non, odit libero reiciendis temporibus voluptatibus sunt laborum quasi velit? Vero et obcaecati cum molestiae? Vitae, ab dolor?
  Quaerat eligendi ipsam doloremque magnam aliquam vel odio blanditiis a. Ex pariatur, nobis in cumque facere possimus quod aspernatur ducimus officia perspiciatis voluptas dolorum error omnis aliquid, voluptatibus nam? Aperiam.
  Commodi repudiandae at consequuntur rerum quia in animi! Labore voluptatibus vitae, libero laudantium ab recusandae consequatur velit sit! Doloremque, neque similique repellat quae eligendi ullam optio blanditiis vero? Tenetur, quam!
</div>
```